# In Unity I messed up and used a infinite while loop and now its stuck on Application.EnterPlayMode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinite

I used an infinite while loop in my script now its stuck on Hold on **Application . Enter Play Mode** i cant click of and i don't know if its saved I have tried changing the script and saving it but its not updating, its been stuck on it for an hour and 20 minutes now.

I have also tried clicking all around the screen, to find out i can move the pop-up but i can not get rid of it.

I need to know if i close down that unity window will it save or how to get rid off the pop-up.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + P if are able to receive frames.

If not, try this guide to save your work.
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/05/24/breakout-how-to-stop-an-infinite-loop-in-a-unity-c-script/?_ga=2.163079608.560681904.1598366242-918877408.1598366242

Comment: Sadly it did not work and the 2nd method is a little too complicated for my brain to understand :(.

Comment: Everything is unknown to everyone, till they learn it. Try giving it ago.